# Requiring app module from within another app module with Typescript

Tags: node.js, requirejs, typescript

I'm building a NodeJS application with Typescript, using [typescript-require](https://github.com/eknkc/typescript-require) to compile my source code. One of my modules exports an interface that I'd like to implement in another of my modules.

Given the following app structure, it does not appear possible to have one app-level module require another:

```
| app/
| -- node_modules/
| ---- interface/
| ------ index.ts
| ---- implements/
| ------ index.ts
```

Trying to import `interface` from inside `implements`..

```
import Interface = require('interface');
```

.. results in the following error:

```
error TS2307: Cannot find external module 'interface'.
```

This works if `implements` is at the app root level.

I can import the module just fine if I use `var` instead of `import`, but then I cannot implement the interface properly.

Is there any way around this? Is this a limitation of typescript-require that I'm stuck with? Is there a better way to be able to write my Node modules in Typescript and be able to compile them on the fly?

#### Additional Information

1. I've tried using [app-module-path](https://github.com/patrick-steele-idem/app-module-path-node), but that package explicitly prevents modules from requiring other modules in the `node_modules` folder. Judging by the error above, I'm doubting compilation is even getting that far.

Answer (score 0):

> there a better way to be able to write my Node modules in Typescript

You need to use *full relative path*. There is discussion to remove this limitation : https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2338

> and be able to compile them on the fly

I wrote an IDE plugin that makes a:) relative paths easier (https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/#relative-paths) and b.) does CompileOnSave (https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/#compile-on-save)

Comment: What do you mean by _full relative path_?

Comment: And thanks for the Atom links, but I'm not using it and don't want my build pipeline to rely on any one IDE.

Comment: full relative path : Instead of `require('interface')` do `require('./interface/index')`